# filereader file format not recongnising json and geojson

Tags: javascript, typescript, filereader

I'm using filereader in Angular 2. I know that the file format can be accessed through:

```
 file.type
```

when I load for example txt, the type is: text/plain.
But when I load a json or geojson the returned value is empty.

is there any reliable way to access to the types when its json, or geojson ?

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way to know if it is json or not would be to test the contents. Meaning run it through `JSON.parse()`. If it throws an exception out it isn't json (or is malformed json).

```
try {
  JSON.parse(fileContents);
} catch(e){
  console.log("Not a json file or file containing malformed json");
}
```

Mime types aren't stored as some piece of data inside files. It is usually determined by extension, magic number (binary header), etc. And depending on implementation, the browser is more than likely just going to look at the extension and use some lookup table. It would seem the browser you used did not have one set for a `.json` file

For instance loading a `.json` file in the below demo in Chrome will show `application/json`. Changing it to `.txt` will make it see it as `text/plain`. Changing it to some other extension will change it yet again.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change',function (){
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',this.files[0].type+"<br>");
});
```

```html
<input type="file" /><br>
```